# Find the general solution of $y(x)$ in $xe^{2y}y'-1-e^{2y}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of $y(x)$ in $xe^{2y}y'-1-e^{2y}=0$.

I'm just starting with diff equations and I'm having a really hard time solving them.

**Here's what I've been doing:**

I re-wrote the equation as:

$xe^{2y}\frac{dy}{dx}-1-e^{2y}=0$, and then I ordered it as

$\frac{1}{x}dx$=$\frac{e^{2y}}{1+e^{2y}}dy$.

And I found the integral of both sides:

$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \int \frac{e^{2y}}{1+e^{2y}}dy $

$\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(e^{2y}+1)}{2}+c$.

I re-order it, and I still can't get any of the solutions... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do the possible solutions look like?

Comment: You could write your $c$ differently like $\ln(k)$ .  You could then use some properties of log to rewrite your solution from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to solve for $y$ using logarithm and exponential rules. Below, I use the notation $c$ for a constant $c \in \mathbb R$ not the same between each step (as well known, any form of a constant can be re-written as simply a constant) :

$$2\ln(x) = \ln(e^{2y}+1) + c \Leftrightarrow e^{2y}+1 = e^{2\ln(x)-c} \Leftrightarrow e^{2y}+1 = cx^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$e^{2y}=cx^2-1 \implies y = \frac{1}{2}\ln(cx^2-1)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! :-)